# mysql: setting a charset and collation on the DB level

Tags: mysql, collation

I'd like to set charset and collation to the db, such that any new table created with no collation specified will have this collation.

I heard it's possible. Is it?
Is it possible to do it by means of code or only from configuration files? 
If it is possible by means of code, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
[client]
default-character-set=charset_name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-configuration.html

To do with code, I believe you would just have to make sure to set the character set at the beginning of your application loads (which I don't think is the answer you're looking for).